# Error testing a keras Model in Watson Studio

Tags: python, postman, ibm-watson, watson-ml

I am trying to test my deployed model.
I deployed my model successfully 
[See the deploy here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPiCR.png).

Then I test the deploy from CLI in the notebook and it works for me [Look the test from NoteBook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUghU.png)

But when I am trying to test the model from Postman, it returns the next Error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyu3R.png)

I appreciate any advice or help

Comment: Ok this is interesting. It seems your endpoint is producing values like 1. , 2. , 3. etc.... Which in *some* languages means "An Integer but stored as type Float". Reading the RFC for JSON, it seems like this is actually permitted even though it probably shouldnt be, and the curiousconcept (look it up, its your new best friend) json validator (Which likely uses regex's from the spec) accepts it. BUT, Chrome (and thus Postman) does not. Fix that end point to return 1. as 1.0 and that'll fix at least some of the bugginess. Weird little edge case you found there...

Comment: Thank you!! it works !!